# Select distinct rows based on column and two conditions in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to retrieve rows from this data set where a T1/T3 value exists, but no T2/T3 value exists for a corresponding ID.

```
ID  sample1 sample2 value
A_000002    T2  T3  -0.934119
A_000002    T1  T3  -0.866637
A_000029    T2  T3  -1.07677
A_000037    T2  T3  -0.76506
A_000057    T1  T3  -5.34988
```

I'd like to say something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE DISTINCT ID
AND sample_1 == "T1"
AND sample_2 == "T3"
```

...and return only the following because it has no corresponding T2/T3 row for that ID:

```
A_000057    T1  T3  -5.34988
```

If I use sample_1 and sample_2 conditions, I get distinct values anyway because it filters out the the "T2" values before checking if the ID is distinct.

The closest I've come is to make 3 tables with the possible T1/T2/T3 combinations and screen for NOT EXISTS T1T2.ID = T2T3.ID

```
select * from T1T2
where not exists (select * from T2T3 where T2T3.id = T1T2.id)
and not exists (select * from T1T3 where T1T3._id = T1T2.id)
order by id
```

I'm not sure I trust the code yet though.

Comment: Edited it to include progress.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where (sample1 = 'T1' and sample2 = 'T3') and
       not exists (select 1 
                   from table t1 
                   where t1.id = t.id and 
                         t1.sample1 = 'T2' and t1.sample2 = 'T3'
                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this technique based on an outer join:

```
select t1.*
from table t1
left join table t2
on t2.id = t1.id
  and t2.sample1 = 'T2' and t2.sample2 = 'T3'
where t1.sample1 = 'T1' and t1.sample2 = 'T3'
and t2.id is null
```

It works because outer joins return nulls if there's no join, and you return only those via the `t2.id is null` condition in the `where` clause.

The big advantage of this technique is the efficient use of the index on the `id` column; this technique will generally out-perform other apporaches. Plus IMHO it's a neater looking query.

Note that the condition for the `sample` columns must be in the *join* condition for `t2`, otherwise you'd effectively get an *inner* join, defeating the required outer join.

Comment: This may be confusing on my part, but my data is a single table and T1 and T2 are short for "Time 1" and "Time 2".  There may be duplicate IDs because T1, T2, T3 are binary comparisons that determine the difference between timepoints.  So I want to return only the rows where "Time 1" and "Time 3" exist for a single ID, but no "Time 2"/"Time 3" exists for that same ID.

Comment: @user974887 `t1` and `t2` are *aliases* for each of the references to `table`, without which references to columns in `table` would be ambiguous. This query returns what you want, ie *only the rows where "Time 1" and "Time 3" exist for a single ID, but no "Time 2"/"Time 3" exists for that same ID*

Comment: @user974887 Huh? How can SQL "crash your browser" or cause you to "lose your code"?

Comment: Basically that.  DB Browser for SQLite froze when I ran it and my command history/new tables I put together were not saved.  Tried it twice and my SQL browser doesn't like the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `not exists`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE t.sample_1 = 'T1' AND t.sample_2 = 'T3' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t2 WHERE t2.id = t.id);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here will surly work:

Select distinct ID, * from table
Where sample1 = 't1' and sample2 = 't3'

Comment: That doesn't work because I want to exclude other T1/T2/T3 combinations, not simply screen for uniques.